# can't understand the parameter after JS function

Tags: javascript, function

Someone wrote this function for mouse detection. But I really don't understand how it works. So I had few questions about the function.

```js
 document.onmousemove = (function() {
  var onmousestop = function() {
    /* do stuff */
    console.log('STOP');
  }, thread;

  return function() {
 clearTimeout(thread);
    console.log(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);
    
  };
})();
```

there is a part where we have function(){},thread;
what does that part actually mean? What does the parameter after } of a function indicates?

Comment: Just like `var x = 5, y = 6`, declares two variables at once while only using one `var` (or `let` or `const`) at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var onmousestop = function() {
        /* do stuff */
        console.log('STOP');
    }, thread;
```

is equivalent to

```
var onmousestop = function() {
        /* do stuff */
        console.log('STOP');
    };
var thread;
```

The return function

```
return function() {
    clearTimeout(thread);
    console.log(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);
};
```

is doing two things. 1) `clearTimeout(thread);` cancels any previously scheduled (and still pending) call to `onmousestop`. 2) `thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);` schedules a call to onmousetop in 500ms and sets `thread` to what is essentially an id to identify the scheduled action (so that it can be cancelled).

Comment: @MAHDI, I've updated my answer to explain the return function.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare multiple variables at once by separating them with a comma.

```
var a = function(){}, thread;
```

this means `a` is an empty function, and `thread` is declared but `undefined`

`thread` is a variable being declared within the first function returned, and then initialized within the second.

The timeout causes a recursive function call after 500 ms, where the initial function is called again.

Answer (score 1):

Let's step by step

```
(function() {
  var onmousestop = function() {
    /* do stuff */
    console.log('STOP');
  }, thread;

  return function() {
 clearTimeout(thread);
    console.log(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);

  };
})();
```

That is a self-run function, which same with

```
function t() {
      var onmousestop = function() {
        /* do stuff */
        console.log('STOP');
      }, thread;

      return function() {
        clearTimeout(thread);
        console.log(thread);
        thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);

      };
    }
t()
```

So the code is like:

```
var onmousestop = function() {
    /* do stuff */
    console.log('STOP');
};
var thread;
document.onmousemove = function() {
clearTimeout(thread);
    console.log(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);
  };
```